# How to find the highest value of the day for each session in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I find the highest value of the day for each session?

Night Session is between 18.00 to 09.30 (this is from one day to the following day)
Day session is between 09.30 - 16.15 (this is on the same day)

I have read about MAXIFS function:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817?hl=en-GB

But I don't know how to code:

> Find highest value between time 18.00 from previous day and 09.30 the current day...

```
Time    High    Low Open    Close   Volume  High of the Day Low of the Day
1/5/2020 0:15:00    2864,25 2859,25 2862,75 2861    3041        
1/5/2020 0:45:00    2866,75 2860,25 2861    2864,75 3227        
1/5/2020 1:15:00    2866,25 2860,75 2864,75 2862,5  2137        
1/5/2020 1:45:00    2866    2853,75 2862,5  2856    4624        
1/5/2020 2:15:00    2861,5  2850,25 2856    2854    9587        
1/5/2020 2:45:00    2855,25 2846,5  2854    2846,75 8691        
1/5/2020 3:15:00    2847,5  2836,5  2847    2841,75 12575       
1/5/2020 3:45:00    2843,75 2830,75 2841,75 2833,5  16739       
1/5/2020 4:15:00    2842,25 2832,75 2833,25 2842    15641       
1/5/2020 4:45:00    2849,5  2840    2842    2845,25 13677       
1/5/2020 5:15:00    2850,75 2842,25 2845,25 2847,25 10265       
1/5/2020 5:45:00    2847,25 2841,25 2847    2843,75 6425        
1/5/2020 6:15:00    2848,75 2841,25 2843,75 2848,5  7384        
1/5/2020 6:45:00    2851    2846    2848,5  2847,25 7615        
1/5/2020 7:15:00    2849,5  2842    2847,25 2843,5  10551       
1/5/2020 7:45:00    2845,25 2836,25 2843,5  2844    13411       
1/5/2020 8:15:00    2847,75 2840,25 2844    2842,75 16715       
1/5/2020 8:45:00    2844,75 2838,75 2842,5  2841,5  12881       
1/5/2020 9:15:00    2847,75 2839,5  2841,75 2847,5  18611       
1/5/2020 9:30:00    2854    2846,75 2847,5  2850,25 18720       
1/5/2020 10:00:00   2857,75 2840,75 2850,25 2847,5  147578      
1/5/2020 10:30:00   2856,5  2838,25 2847,5  2847,5  143251      
1/5/2020 11:00:00   2853,75 2842,25 2847,5  2847,75 84208       
1/5/2020 11:30:00   2847,75 2835,25 2847,75 2835,5  64264       
1/5/2020 12:00:00   2836,25 2820,75 2835,5  2823,75 97264       
1/5/2020 12:30:00   2826,75 2816,25 2823,5  2820    94263       
1/5/2020 13:00:00   2823,5  2812,75 2820    2819,5  73351       
1/5/2020 13:30:00   2824    2812,25 2819,5  2818    59251       
1/5/2020 14:00:00   2820,75 2811,75 2818    2816    58513       
1/5/2020 14:30:00   2824,75 2812    2815,75 2823,5  61097       
1/5/2020 15:00:00   2824    2816,75 2823,75 2822    46790       
1/5/2020 15:30:00   2830,5  2819    2822    2823,75 76846       
1/5/2020 16:00:00   2826    2812,75 2823,75 2823,75 207138      
1/5/2020 16:15:00   2827,25 2821    2824    2821,25 56684       
3/5/2020 18:30:00   2797    2781,25 2789    2784,25 31974       
3/5/2020 19:00:00   2787,25 2776,25 2784,25 2781    12576       
3/5/2020 19:30:00   2786    2776,25 2781,25 2784,25 10187       
3/5/2020 20:00:00   2784,5  2773    2784,5  2777,25 10004       
3/5/2020 20:30:00   2783,75 2777,25 2777,25 2779,25 11394       
3/5/2020 21:00:00   2783    2771    2779,25 2775,75 11334       
3/5/2020 21:30:00   2789,75 2775,5  2775,75 2789,25 13250       
3/5/2020 22:00:00   2795,25 2785,5  2789,25 2793,75 11736       
3/5/2020 22:30:00   2793,5  2788    2793,5  2793    5884        
3/5/2020 23:00:00   2796,75 2791,75 2792,75 2795    4820        
3/5/2020 23:30:00   2803,5  2795    2795    2798,75 7860        
4/5/2020 0:00:00    2806,5  2798    2798,5  2806,5  5127        
4/5/2020 0:30:00    2808    2796,5  2806,5  2796,5  4867        
4/5/2020 1:00:00    2800,75 2795    2796,5  2798,5  4357        
4/5/2020 1:30:00    2803    2795,5  2798,5  2799,75 5682        
4/5/2020 2:00:00    2799,75 2792,25 2799,5  2794,5  5935        
4/5/2020 2:30:00    2805,25 2792    2794,5  2801,5  13373       
4/5/2020 3:00:00    2814,5  2800    2801,25 2809,75 13251       
4/5/2020 3:30:00    2812,75 2795,5  2809,75 2798    21247       
4/5/2020 4:00:00    2807    2797,25 2797,75 2800,75 21610       
4/5/2020 4:30:00    2808,25 2794,5  2801    2799,25 19936       
4/5/2020 5:00:00    2799,5  2793    2799,25 2794,5  18011       
4/5/2020 5:30:00    2795    2783,5  2794,25 2784,25 19423       
4/5/2020 6:00:00    2796,25 2783,75 2784    2796,25 14999       
4/5/2020 6:30:00    2802    2792,75 2796    2798,25 16085       
4/5/2020 7:00:00    2800,75 2794,25 2798,25 2796,5  12949       
4/5/2020 7:30:00    2800    2793,25 2796,5  2797,75 11169       
4/5/2020 8:00:00    2805,5  2797,5  2797,75 2800    17097       
4/5/2020 8:30:00    2807,25 2796,5  2800    2806,5  22897       
4/5/2020 9:00:00    2808    2800    2806,5  2801,5  26588       
4/5/2020 9:30:00    2807    2797,25 2801,25 2804,25 38232       
4/5/2020 10:00:00   2806,75 2788,5  2804,25 2802,5  149710      
4/5/2020 10:30:00   2817,75 2801,25 2802,25 2808    108149      
4/5/2020 11:00:00   2812,25 2803    2807,75 2803,75 85289       
4/5/2020 11:30:00   2814    2801,75 2803,75 2806,5  72006       
4/5/2020 12:00:00   2815,5  2804    2806,5  2810,75 65144       
4/5/2020 12:30:00   2816    2809,25 2811    2815,25 37964       
4/5/2020 13:00:00   2817,25 2805,75 2815,5  2807,5  41952       
4/5/2020 13:30:00   2809,5  2798,5  2807,5  2804,5  53301       
4/5/2020 14:00:00   2811,5  2804,25 2804,25 2810,75 32541       
4/5/2020 14:30:00   2814,75 2808,5  2810,75 2811,75 38114       
4/5/2020 15:00:00   2822,5  2807,25 2811,75 2821,25 77435       
4/5/2020 15:30:00   2830,5  2819    2821,25 2829,25 66760       
4/5/2020 16:00:00   2835,75 2827,5  2829    2833,5  141731      
4/5/2020 16:15:00   2833,5  2824    2833,25 2825,25 46808       
4/5/2020 16:45:00   2827    2823,25 2826,25 2826    4724        
4/5/2020 17:15:00   2828,25 2826    2826    2827,5  2005        
4/5/2020 18:15:00   2831    2824,5  2827    2829,25 2632        
4/5/2020 18:45:00   2833,75 2829,25 2829,5  2829,75 3116        
4/5/2020 19:15:00   2830,25 2825,5  2830    2828,75 3005        
4/5/2020 19:45:00   2830    2827    2829    2829,25 1593        
4/5/2020 20:15:00   2837,75 2827,75 2829,5  2836    4976        
4/5/2020 20:45:00   2837    2831,25 2836    2836    4144        
4/5/2020 21:15:00   2844    2835,5  2836    2840,75 7236        
4/5/2020 21:45:00   2846,5  2838,75 2841    2845,5  6021        
4/5/2020 22:15:00   2848    2843,5  2845,75 2846    5023        
4/5/2020 22:45:00   2848    2843,75 2845,75 2844    3776        
4/5/2020 23:15:00   2845    2841,75 2844    2843    3423        
4/5/2020 23:45:00   2845,5  2840,25 2843    2842    2935        
5/5/2020 0:15:00    2847,25 2841,5  2842    2847,25 2181        
5/5/2020 0:45:00    2847,5  2843    2847    2846,25 2072        
5/5/2020 1:15:00    2852    2845,5  2846,25 2848,25 5176        
5/5/2020 1:45:00    2849,5  2846,75 2848,25 2848    1833        
5/5/2020 2:15:00    2852,5  2845    2848,25 2851,25 5633        
5/5/2020 2:45:00    2851,25 2846    2851,25 2847    4947        
5/5/2020 3:15:00    2854    2846    2847    2851,75 14396       
5/5/2020 3:45:00    2863,75 2849,75 2852    2861,25 20664       
5/5/2020 4:15:00    2865    2858,25 2861,25 2860,75 14717       
5/5/2020 4:45:00    2864    2845,25 2860,75 2848    25575       
5/5/2020 5:15:00    2848,5  2832,5  2847,75 2842    30640       
5/5/2020 5:45:00    2849,75 2839,5  2842    2849    15625       
5/5/2020 6:15:00    2856,5  2846,5  2849    2851    14150
```

source data:
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MThctCQSxBsd94WK-yEeb8evTRq2FUv7r5i5TATneNo/edit?usp=sharing][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AGGREGATE` function.

For night session:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(A:A>(J2-1+TIME(18,0,0)))*(A:A<=(J2+TIME(9,30,0)))*B:B,1)
```

For day session:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(A:A>(J2+TIME(9,30,0)))*(A:A<=(J2+TIME(16,15,0)))*B:B,1)
```

[image]